# Order totals block on Magento order email and invoice email templates

Tags: templates, magento, customization, templating, theming

Can anyone point me to the templates/code blocks that are used for the order totals block on the Magento order mail and invoice e-mail templates?

The tax issue is solved but I need to implement some logic to get rid of the shipping and the subtotal. Which templates are used for the emails? 
I found the frontend and changed this as needed, but can't find the template/block that is used for the e-mails sent by the system.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 16):

Niels answer of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml` is correct however I thought some further clarification was in order because one doesn't merely make cosmetic changes to this file in order to effect the desired change. `totals.phtml` loops over the "totals", each of which produces a total-related line-item (Subtotal, Shipping & Handling, Tax, Grand Total (Excl. Tax), and Grand Total (Incl. Tax)). Your best bet is to use `Mage::Log` to output each of the totals (which are looped over via an associative array `$_code => $total`). If you log each key (`$_code`), you'll see names such as `subtotal`, `shipping`, `grand_total`, `tax`, and `grand_total_incl`. I filtered out those from the sales order e-mail that I didn't want by adding the following code directly below the `foreach`:

```
<?php if (in_array($_code, array('grand_total'))) { 
    continue;
} ?>
```

Hopefully this will help anybody who is puzzling over where these totals are mysteriously coming from. :-)

Comment: genius, I would never have thought of this :)

Comment: Great! Works in Magento 1.9

Comment: Kinda late, but for everyone that reads this thread, this is also the file which is used for the sales order view in the frontend of the shop. So every change you'll make, will be shown on the frontend on the "Order page". /sales/order/view/order_id/XXX

Comment: I want to remove the line "Grand Total to be Charged from", how can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

This template is being used for the totals in the e-mail templates and order overview in My Account:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml

Comment: Kinda late, but for everyone that reads this thread, this is also the file which is used for the sales order view in the frontend of the shop. So every change you'll make, will be shown on the frontend on the "Order page". /sales/order/view/order_id/XXX

Answer (score 1):

Jason's answer is good for telling Magento to not generate the likes of `grand_total` HTML. However, you should look at **System > Configuration > Sales > Tax** to see if you can remove the fields the proper way first.

If you then see a message saying "Warning tax configuration can result in rounding errors" at the top of your admin pages, you'll need to adjust your settings. See [the manual](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/sales/tax.html?Highlight=tax) for the default settings, if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure but could it be this one:

\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\email\order\items.phtml

Directory might not exactly match yours but I'm sure you would be able to find it.

HTH

Comment: Thx HTH but it did not help alot.  

I wish to use the same logic for the totals on the mail as for displaying them in the frontend (cart & order review during checkout). Adjusting the templates did not have the required result. 

Will dig a little further... When I find it I will post it. 

In the meantime: Any other suggestions?